# download multiple images using php

Tags: php, image

I have a locally hosted site for official use. I need to download a set of images in a single click. I can go to the `image` folder and do it manually. So... I need a `php` code to do this.

Comment: I don't know anything about it..

Answer (score 1):

Check This This will help You

```
<?php

$zipname = 'adcs.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !strstr($entry,'.php')) {
        $zip->addFile($entry);
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}

$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='adcs.zip'");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
header("Location: adcs.zip");

?>
```